# AlarmManager not trigger current time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I making an android alarm app and setting alarm by using code below:

```
Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
alarm.set(Calendar.YEAR, year1);
alarm.set(Calendar.MONTH, month1);
alarm.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day1);
alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour1);
alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min1);
alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

if(alarm.before(Calendar.getInstance()))
{
    alarm.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You selected the past time",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{        
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Everything works fine, but the problem is when I select the current date,month,year and also the current time, it will display "you selected the past time". How to solve this problem?

Comment: You are doing the right stuff, are you sure that the variables, year1, month1, etc, are correct?

Comment: @GiuseppeLabanca Yup, I use the Toast to display and it shows correctly. I don't understand why it will display "You selected..." if I select the current time and also current date

Comment: I think it it because of the fact that until code reaches `if` statement some amout of time has passed. At least in the range of milliseconds. Therefore, you may want to use another calendar object for `rightNow` that is initialized together with `alarm` and use that to compare inside of if.

Comment: @Marat can you show me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Hope that it will solve your problem.

```
Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar copy = (Calendar) alarm.clone();

alarm.set(Calendar.YEAR, year1);
alarm.set(Calendar.MONTH, month1);
alarm.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day1);
alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour1);
alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min1);

int result = alarm.compareTo(copy);

if (result == 0) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You selected current time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if (result < 0)
{
    alarm.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You selected the past time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{        
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: What does the `result==0` and `result < 0` mean ? I tried your code but it still display "You selected the past time".

Comment: I have editted the answer. I deleted line where you set `seconds` of the `alarm`. Now it should work. If `alarm` is equal to `copy` then result is set to 0. If it is before then result is set to number less than 0. If it is after the result is bigger than 0

Comment: Thanks. Since I want to let the alarm execute the current time and date, I can remove the  `result==0` , and just write if `(result < 0)`, else `{}` ?

Comment: That should also work. Test that out and let me know